# Why dosent the script hide shortcut to .bat file

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe, file-shortcut

```
***--------------------------
LOGON.INK -> LOGON.BAT:
--------------------------***

@echo off

title En@rypted Passwords - Login

color 0B

taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe


*attrib +h login.ink* **(logon.bat i use .ink becuse i use icons)**    *

*attrib -h logout.ink* **(logout.bat i use .ink becuse i use icons)**    *

attrib -h Snapchat.txt

attrib -h Instagram.txt

attrib -h Google+.txt

attrib -h GMX.txt

tree C:\Program Files (x86)

cls

echo You'r now signed in.

start explorer

pause

start D:\
```

---

I have the opposite just for logoff.bat...
I use it on a D:\ (Memory Stick)

### Windows 10

Comment: Is the link in the working directory of the script? Also, do you mean .lnk?

Comment: How do i hide shorcuts?  i can hide .txt and .bat.   but i cannot hide the a .ink (shortcut)

Comment: And what did you mean by "   
Is the link in the working directory of the script? Also, do you mean .lnk?  "? Did you mean if the shortcut works? if so yes, it opens the logon.bat and logoff.bat.

Comment: No, I mean "did you mean .lnk", as in the file extension for a shortcut/link. .ink is no standard file extension. The working or current directory (`%cd%`) is where the batch file operates. Either `cd` into the desired directory or use absolute paths. `attrib +h short.lnk` hides the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you do wrong, but the following works on Windows 10:

Batch file called "test.cmd" with a shortcut to it named "test.lnk":

```
attrib +h test.lnk && REM "hide file"
pause
attrib -h test.lnk && REM "unhide file"
```

It hides the shortcut, pauses and unhides the shortcut.
This works both from the shortcut and the batch-file.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]